# Binary search Not checking middle value

Tags: python

So i'm trying to program an iterative binary search that does not compare the value with the half-middle index until (lower_bound - upper_bound) <= 1. To try to make less comparisons of items. I want to only compare if the difference of the lower and upper is <= 1.

The code below loops through all of first_list items and compares it with second_list, if first_list item is found in second_list then append to list_found. However the output of list_found seems to not be correct. for example if i add a value in second_list that is in first_list it doesn't show up in list_found.

also list_found seems to always only print out one value, even if there is multiple same items in first_list and second_list.

```
   first_list = [1,2,3 ..... values]
   second_list = [values.....]
   list_found = [] 
   comparisons = 0
   for i in first_list:
        upper_bound = len(second_genome) - 1
        lower_bound = 0        
        stop = False
        while stop is False:
            middle = (lower_bound + upper_bound) // 2
            comparisons += 1
            if second_list[middle] <= i:
                lower_bound = middle
            else:
                upper_bound = middle

            if lower_bound - upper_bound <= 1:
                comparisons += 1
                if middle == 0:
                    if second_list[middle + 1] == i:
                        list_found.append(i)
                        stop = True

                if second_list[middle] == i:
                    list_found.append(i)
                stop = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use sets ? 
Computing intersections on sets should be far more efficient than on list, because no loop is required.

If your input is :

```
first_list = [1,3,5,7,9]
second_list = [0,3,6,9]
```

Your output can be:

```
found_set = set(first_list).intersection(set(second_list))

print(found_set)
output: set([9, 3])
```

And then you can iterate over your found_set as you would have done with found_list.

PS: note that set elements are unique, so duplicate elements in first_list will appear only once in found_set

Answer (score 0):

> **Typo**: `upper_bound = len(second_genome) - 1`

I assume this should be: `upper_bound = len(second_list) - 1`

> **Question**: To try to make less comparisons of items

I don't see the benefits to doing so.
Your Code uses **6 Comparisons**, default Binary Search uses **4 Comparsions**.
**Rethink your approach!**

> **Question**: ... list_found seems to always only print out one value.
>   if i add a value in second_list that is in first_list it doesn't show up in list_found

This is because your `middle` does not **iterate**:

> **Data**:
>
> ```
> first_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> second_list = [3,4,5]
> ```
>
> **Output**:
>
> ```
> second_list[1](4) == 1 l/u:-1
> second_list[1](4) == 2 l/u:-1
> second_list[1](4) == 3 l/u:-1
> second_list[1](4) == 4 l/u:-1
> second_list[1](4) == 5 l/u:-1
> second_list[1](4) == 6 l/u:-1
> list_found:[4]
> ```